# How do I handle exception thrown by a custom tag which is called in a JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, exception, tags

My JSP page is calling a custom tag and that tag throws **jspException** in `doStartTag` method; the exception text is being displayed on UI.

### Important points:

- Don't have option to use a common error page for exceptions.
- Already tried `TryCatchFinally` interface, `doCatch()` does not get executed for some reason.
- Don't have option to not throw exception explicitly from `doStartTag` method, as it will execute `"return EVAL_PAGE;"`